# Как вставить текст в html который находится в переменной?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  let raskroy_one_list_start = "" +
      "                        <div class=\"one-list\">\n" +
      "                            <span class=\"profil_name\"></span>\n" +
      "                            <div class=\"raskroy-wrapper\">";
```

Мне нужно вставить текст через javascript/jquery в span с классом profil_name.
Если бы это уже лежало в документе, то я бы использовал привычное для себя решение:

```
$(".profil_name").text(sometext);
```

Пока все что на ум приходит - это for-ом как строку перебирать и вставлять в нужном месте, но мне кажется что это костыль. Нет ли для этого какого-нибудь метода вроде того что я привел в пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно советуют не парсить HTML регулярками и не создавать велосипедов, а пользоваться штатными средствами:

```js
let raskroy_one_list_start = `
  <div class="one-list">
  <span class="profil_name"></span>
  <div class="raskroy-wrapper">
`; 

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
  raskroy_one_list_start, "text/html"
);
doc.querySelector(".profil_name").textContent = 'foo';
raskroy_one_list_start = doc.body.innerHTML;

console.log(raskroy_one_list_start);
```

Comment: Или просто `const markup = \`/*....*/ <span class="profil_name">${sometext}</span> /*....*/\`;` без использования DOMParser'а, и далее `$(anyElement).html(markup);`.

Comment: @yar85 Да, если создание строки с разметкой в нашей власти.